# How is the product backlog in TFS filtering work items by default?

Tags: tfs

When I go into the backlog (Epics) of a TFS project, it is showing a list of items/epics.  If I add an epic to that project, it does not show up in the list.  Is there a way to set the filtration/query criteria that the product backlog is showing by default?

I noticed that the "area path" that shows up in all of the epics when I open the backlog is the same (e.g. "A\B").  However, the area path I set for my epic that does not show up in the product backlog is sub-path (e.g. "A\B\C").  If I change my area path to "A\B", then it shows up in the product backlog.  So there must be something somewhere that is setting the criteria to only look at a specific area.  Where is that defined and how do I set the criteria so I can look at either everything in "A\B" and below or just items in "A\B\C"?

By the way I am using: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.131.27701.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the backlog determined according to the areas and iterations.

You can configure which areas & iteration will be in the backlog in this way:

Go to the team admin page:

[image]

On the "Work" tab click on "Areas":

[image]

Click on "Select area(s)" and choose the area you want to will be in the backlog:

[image]

Before I added a new area:

[image]

After:

[image]

More info find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=vsts&tabs=previous-nav).